# *Unix как удалить все файлы не затрагивая папки?

Tags: unix

Назрел вопрос, есть структура например:
/uploads/images/
/uploads/images/crop/
/uploads/images/thumb/

Как удалить все файлы не затрагивая папки "crop/thumb"?) Ручное удаление уже практикуеться, и оно не очень мне то и нравиться)

Comment: всё-таки непонятно, нужно ли удалять файлы в других подпапках, если они там будут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /uploads/ -type f | xargs rm
```

Comment: Пардон, но это в корне неверно! Таким образом будут удалены ВСЕ файлы в дереве /uploads. ИМХО, правильно так:find /uploads/ -type f -path /uploads/images/thumb/ -prune | xargs rmМожно и ещё короче:find /uploads/ -type f -path /uploads/images/thumb/ -prune -deleteНо там из-за -depth могут быть нестыковки.

Comment: "Таким образом будут удалены ВСЕ файлы в дереве /uploads" вообще то задача так и поставлена. Перед тем как имхать, вы бы хоть проверили.

Comment: Не проверил потому-что доступа к Unix системе небыло, но принцып был понятен что можно делать через find =)